# Is there method in SQL to grab first n rows, ordered by date, PER ID( not just the first n off the top)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a series of payment records in a database. I need only the first n records FOR EACH id that sum up to less than another column variable(initial invoice) for each ID.

```
select * 
FROM db.paymentrecords
Order by PaymentDate;
```

Is indexing the correct way to deal with this? I'm unsure how to specify to MYSQL to only grab the first n records from each grouping( each grouping is merely all payments for each id).

The idea is to figure out how much has been paid on the invoice cumulatively at any time.

perhaps something along the lines of

```
WHERE sum(first n records in each grouping < aggregate invoice amount)
```

I feel like this should be straightforward, and yet I'm unsure how to do this logically with SQL. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys!

Edit** So it ended up being a bit too complicated in sql for my taste, we switched over and did it programmatically using python to perform the logic we needed. I'm still unsure how to accomplish this in sql with indexing each group of records? Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: Could you add the database structure that you're querying?

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL 8+, you can use window functions:

```
select pr.*,
       sum(amount) over (partition by id order by paymentdate) as running_amount
from db.paymentrecords pr;
```